# Expanding the list of comments doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

This morning I tried expanding the list of comments of an answer, but it doesn't work.
I tried also on Stack Overflow, on [How to quickly theme a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77694/how-to-quickly-theme-a-view) and I was able to expand the list of the comments for that question. It seems it is a issue on EL&U.

EL&U and SO report to be using different revisions of the software; while Stack Overflow uses the 2011.4.4.1 revision, EL&U uses revision 2011.4.4.4.
Still, when I tried on programmers.SE (e.g. on [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)), I was able to expand the list of comments. It seems the problem is specific to EL&U.

I am using Firefox 4.

Comment: It works again for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now fixed, see

[Add comment, flag, delete links are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85884/add-comment-flag-delete-links-are-broken/85895#85895)

for details.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the bug happens when you link to an answer, i.e. the end of the URL contains a # followed by an answer ID. If you delete the # sign and everything after it, then expanding comments works.

I don't remember seeing this before, so it definitely seems like a new bug.

(I'm still on Firefox 3.6.16, FWIW.)